# Tumbling Window trigger dependency's creation

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

I have two pipelines A and B , A needs to be run in every 3 hrs and B needs to be run in every 2 hrs.
A is the one need to run firstly then B.

How could i add these dependencies ?

Comment: According the pipeline trigger execution times, B is triggered more than A. We can't ensure A always triggered firstly than B. Can you explain to us what the meaning of "A is the one need to run firstly then B"?

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @LeonYue Thank you for the reply... The trigger A and its related pipeline needs to be executed first as the second one (B) needs some id's inserted by A.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do this using two tumbling window triggers, where one is dependent on the other one, utilizing **dependency offset** and **dependency size**.

It is well described in the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tumbling-window-trigger-dependency